# Open Excel 2003 XML files (XMLSS) in Excel 2000

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I need to open Excel 2003 XML files (not Open XML from 2007) in Excel 2000.  Is there any plugin that would allow me to do this?

Edit: the name of the format is called XMLSS - XML Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done unfortunately.  You would need to create your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel 2000 is fully updated with available patches, it should have no problems opening XML files generated by Excel 2003.

Comment: Have you tried this (I don't have 2000)?  And are you referring to the Office 2003 [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) and not just a generic XML export data file?

Comment: I haven't had 2000 in years, so perhaps I am mis-remembering.  But as I recall, in the Open File dialog, there was an option to select XML files to open in the file filter dropdown.  Of course, as a developer, I would be tempted to tell anyone still using Office 2000 that they are out of luck.

Comment: Okay, got my hands on 2000 - and it doesn't work.  I don't think this can be done with any current plugins/updates.

Comment: Ah, I must have been thinking of the OpenXML type docs.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en) should grant you the ability you seek.

Comment: That pack is for Open XML from Office 2007+ if you look at the link.  I need it to open the Excel 2003 XML [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats).